# Are joins having derived tables faster than regular joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the bad heading.

My question is which of the below queries would be faster?

Query 1

```
SELECT t1_col1, t1_col2, t2_col2 
FROM t1 JOIN t2
ON t1.t1_col1 = t2.t2_col1
```

Query 2

```
SELECT t1_col1, t1_col2, t2_col2 
FROM 
(SELECT t1_col1, t1_col2
FROM t1) t1 JOIN 
(SELECT t2_col1, t2_col2
FROM t2) t2
ON t1.t1_col1 = t2.t2_col1
```

Assume both the tables t1 and t2 have 1 M+ records and more than 15 columns. Also let's just say there are no indexes on any columns.

I go for the approach 2 as it seems less data would be loaded into memory. But doesn't the SQL Server internally manage that?

I am on PDW 2012.

Comment: There should be no difference in performance.  SQL Server is smart enough to ignore the subqueries where they are not necessary.

Comment: Yes, but would you say option 2 is a bit more foolproof?

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans? They'll probably be the same. If the JOIN uses an index the table is not even loaded before the SELECT.

Comment: What do you mean by "more foolproof"?

Comment: The thing is I have worked on SQL Server long enough to know how smart it is. But I am not so sure PDW or more that matter other RDBMS are that smart or not. If I go for the second approach are there any caveats at all? If it is guaranteed to be either as fast or faster than the first approach, I would happily go for it. I just want to set some guidelines/standards on the code we write.

Comment: If I saw a query written in the style of option 2 I would go talk to the author and ask them why in the world they made a simple query so overly complicated. Why would you prefer bloated syntax that is more difficult to maintain? I am quite confused.

Comment: I agree it appears bloated. I just want to know if there are any trade offs at all. If it helps performance, I would keep my peace with it. Just not sure.

Comment: Adding subqueries is not likely to generate better performance. On the contrary they are more prone to decrease performance. In the case of the query posted they should have identical execution plans. I am curious where the idea of this subquery style came from.

Comment: It came from my understanding that for the joins to happen, data is first loaded into the RAM from the disk. If I "narrow" the data, it would take up lesser space in RAM(i.e. only those columns I specify are pulled, not all) and thus also leads to lesser I/O operations.

Comment: Sean - in my code I am repeating this practice of narrowing columns(using derived tables).  There are no additional subqueries. I hope I am not unintentionally slowing the queries down. The thing is the size and width of our FACT tables are pretty huge and I thus want the most performance friendly querying style.

Comment: Also isn't absence of a derived table the same as doing a "(select * from t1)" operation? I guess our aim should be to reduce dataset size. One more advantage I feel with the derived table technique is that we can filter the data within its scope instead doing it at the end. This I am sure is a tuning technique.

Comment: @SouravA Not quite, the query optimizer parses your query and identifies all of the columns you are using and generates the plan based on a myriad of factors. Start here: [Query Optimizer Deep Dive - Part 1 - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/04/28/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.aspx)

Comment: So last evening, we had a session from MS folks. So it turns out the PDW engine is NOT as sophisticated as SQL engine. It sucks at parsing queries e.g. won't convert a left join to inner join or load only requisite columns in memory, which kind of answers my point. Also, in addition we ran performanxe tests on humassice queries and found the second approac trump the first one. I am not yet answering my question as I am not a 100% sure. But not at 0% surity either :) Hope this gives fuel to thoughts of those who come looking regarding the same question.